# nation or country

Tags: vocabulary

Across the world, in fact, nations don't spur growth so much as dynamic regions-- modern versions of the original megalopolis a term coined by Gottman to identify the sprawling Boston-New York-Washington economic power corridor.

I am wondering if we could **substitute** nation for **country**

Comment: You could, but idiomatically we tend to use ***nation*** when "anthropomorphically" referring to the entity as an *agent* that can ***do*** things, have ideals, etc. (often, *by* the government acting on behalf of the entire country). Whereas ***country*** can often be a much more "passive" entity. This *Britain is a proud nation*, but *Britain is a beautiful country*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Etymologically, in fact, a "nation" is a people, not a state, those 'born' of the same stock; the 'state' sense first appears in the 17th century and does not become the primary meaning until well into the 19th century.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm not going to check the etymology of "country", but I'd like to hope it's more like ***land*** than ***people***. A land can be *beautiful*, and it can be figuratively anthropomorphized as, for example, *bountiful, unforgiving*. But only things like nations and states can do complex volitional things like *spur growth*. Except in usages like [*"When Norman Wisdom went to Albania, the whole country adored him"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Wisdom#Popularity_in_Albania) (but that's a slightly weird one! :).

Answer (score 1):

A country is a geographical region. It is defined by its borders and the land that it occupies. These territories are recognized by other countries. The country must control its own land without claims being made by others.

A nation is a group of people who share the same history and culture.

It is possible for a nation to exist without a country. Best example I could give would be the Native American nations within the United States.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Greg's answer, there are several relevant concepts:

- A **nation** is a group of people who share the same history and culture.  Religion, language, and family relationships are factors many people use in deciding what nation they are a part of.  As Greg indicates, the concept of "nation" is related to the concepts of "tribe" and "ethnic group".  For example, "Serbs" have communities in several "sovereign states".
- A **sovereign state** is a government (and the people and territory it rules).  A "sovereign state" can make its own laws and field its own military.  It has a responsibility to defend its people and territory, subject to "international law".  For example, Serbia, Croatia, Bosnia-Herzegovina, Bulgaria, Macedonia, *et cetera*.  The United States is an unusual case. Theoretically both the federal government and the individual states share "dual sovereignty".  For most purposes of international law, the federal government of the United States exercises sovereignty in the United States.
- A **country** is a region.  It may or may not correspond to a political jurisdiction.  It may be populated by people(s) of one or more "nations"; it may be divided amongst one or more "sovereign states"; it may include entire sovereign state(s); and a "sovereign state" may include part(s) (or all) of one or more "countries".  Typically, people who are from the same country will recognize that they have something in common, even if they are part of different "nations" or "states".  For example, "Lancashire" in England, or "the hill country of Tennessee".
- A **nation-state** is a "sovereign state" that more-or-less corresponds with a "nation" as defined here.  For example, Germany, Poland, or France.
- An **empire** is a "sovereign state" that rules multiple "nations", as defined here.  For example, the Austro-Hungarian empire ruled Germans, Italians, Magyars, and many Slavic nations.

In the original quote, "nation" is being used in the sense of "sovereign state" or "nation state" (specifically the United States of America).  While it would be possible to use the word "country", it would make the quote even less clear.