# Can I say "If not concerning..."?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

> If not concerning currency or anything else related, this country is a great nation.

vs

> Not concerning currency or anything else related, this country is a great nation.

Is the first sentence grammatically correct by adding "if"? Do both sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Provide more context by completing your sentence.

Comment: Do you mean: Regardless of currency or anything else, this is a great nation? Or apart from currency, it's a great nation?

Comment: @Rose In my original mind, I mean If currency problem is included in discussions, this nation may or may not be at the same level of greatness, but if excluded, then it's great.

Comment: Only the version with _if_ is correct, and the sentence will still be awkward. Concerning is a preposition meaning _about_. Does "not about x, y is great" sound correct to you? If not concerning is short for _if_ _it's_ _not_ _concerning_, which, in turn, is short for _if_ _what_ _we_ _are_ _talking_ _about_ _is_ _not_ _concerning_. It's not _usually_ used when making an exception/exclusion; other more common ways include _aside_  _from_,  _apart_ _from_, _not_ _considering_, etc.

Comment: Besides the confusing grammar, the example sentences contain semantic errors. "Country", "government", and "nation" [mean different things](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34822#35503). If the currency (and everything related to it) are embarrassingly bad, then we know that the government has lots of power over the economy, and we know that the government is so bad at using its power over the economy that the government does not understand how bad it is economically. Perhaps the "great nation" "puts up with" a bad form of government.

Comment: Clearer phrasing might help: *Discounting financial considerations*, this country is a great one. Or: *If currency issues are not considered*, this is a great country.